# How to avoid separating table rows in pdf made with DataTable

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatable

When a row does not fit in the page and continues to the next, rows are being split in two from the previous page's last row to next page's first row. can I make it not be included in the first page if it doesn't fit?

[image]

The encircled rows in the pic should be in one row.

```
text: 'PDF',
extend: 'pdfHtml5',
filename: 'Inventory',
orientation: 'portrait', //portrait
pageSize: 'A4', //A3 , A5 , A6 , legal , letter
exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible',
    search: 'applied',
    order: 'applied'
},
customize: function (doc) {
    //Remove the title created by datatTables
    doc.content.splice(0,1);
    doc.pageMargins = [20,90,20,30];
    var logo = 'data:image/png;'
    doc.styles = {
        tableHeader: {
            bold: false,
            fontSize: 10.5,
            color: 'red',
            alignment: 'center'
        },
        defaultStyle: {
            fontSize: 10,
            color: 'black'
        },
        tableBodyOdd: {
            alignment: 'center'

        },
        tableBodyEven: {
            alignment: 'center'
        },
    }
}
```

I found out that there is a property dontBreakRows that can be set to true or false, but I'm not sure how to implement it or if it is what I need to fix my problem.
Thank you.

Comment: This could be two different problems depending on what's actually happening, but I can't tell. Are you saying that it's splitting content that should be in one row into two rows because the table overflows onto a second page?

Comment: And you'll need to show your code here if you want some actual answers.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusing question and lack of content but thank you for your reply. Yes that is exactly my problem. The content of the row is being split into the second page. Also I edited my question for some code. I hope it can help and again, thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you are actually initializing DataTables? Should be a line with something like: `var table = $('#tableId').DataTable({`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the break rows setting here:

```
text: 'PDF',
extend: 'pdfHtml5',
filename: 'Inventory',
orientation: 'portrait', //portrait
dontBreakRows: true, //<--insert here in your code
```

This should give you want you need.